# How do I view html page in Spring Boot mvc?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

The text "index" is displayed when I enter localhost:8080. I want that "hello world" should be display as this is the body content of the index.html. I have a Controller class

```
package com.steinko.reactspringboottutorial.webserver;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")

}
```

And Application class:

```
package com.steinko.reactspringboottutorial.webserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication

public class FrontendWebServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FrontendWebServer.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am building the application with Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.steinko.reactspringboottutorial.webserver'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Greenwich.SR1")
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.2.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}
```

My index.html file is placed in /src/main/resources/templates/index.html
 Looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title> Todo </title>
</head>

<body>
 <p>hello world</p>
</body>
```

How do I fix this program so that the "hello world" is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){

        return "index";
    }

}
```

**Edit**:

Add `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` in dependencies

Comment: I change to @Controller  then I get a error message in the browser: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jun 11 15:50:46 CEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available                                                                                                          How do I fix that error

Comment: I fixed it by adding implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf' in dependencies of gradel.build